Stable homotopy of vector bundles
Consider the category $\mathsf{VectBun}$ of real vector bundles over topological spaces, where
the morphisms are bundle maps that are fiberwise isomorphisms.
This category has a stabilization functor
that sends a bundle $\xi \to B$
to $\xi \oplus \underline{\mathbb{R}}$,
where $\underline{\mathbb{R}}$
denotes the trivial line bundle over $B$.
Mimicking the definition of spectra,
one can then define a category $\mathsf{StVectBun}$ of stable objects
given by sequences of vector bundles $(\xi_n)_{n \geq 0}$
along with structure maps
$\xi_n \oplus \underline{\mathbb{R}} \to \xi_{n+1}$.
Let me call such an object a stable vector bundle.
For simplicity, in the following discussion
I will restrict to stable bundles of rank $0$,
which means that $\xi_n$ has rank $n$.
A stable vector bundle $\xi = (\xi_n)_{n \geq 0}$ has an associated Thom spectrum
made up of the Thom spaces of the bundles $\xi_n$.
This gives a functor from $\mathsf{StVectBun}$ to (sequential) spectra.
I expect that one can do stable homotopy with stable vector bundles
in a way that is analogous to spectra.
More precisely, I expect that there should be model structure on the category
of stable bundles that interacts nicely with the Thom spectrum functor.
Naïvely, I would like to define a stable equivalence
of stable bundles as a map that induces a stable equivalence of Thom spectra.
I don't really know how the rest of the structure should work out, though.
Question
Is there a model structure
on the category $\mathsf{StVectBun}$
whose weak equivalences
are the maps that induce stable equivalences of Thom spectra?
Has this point of view on stable vector bundles ever been studied in the litterature?
Context/motivation
Stable vector bundles appear in bordism theory as classifying objects
for certain "stable structures" on manifolds,
such as orientations, stable almost complex structures, stable framings, etc.
It seems that a more common approach to this in the litterature
is to take as a starting point the category $\mathsf{Top}_{BO}$
of spaces over $BO$ (or $BO \times \mathbb{Z}$ if one considers bundles of arbitrary rank). Presumably, these two points of view
are equivalent in a certain sense, and I would like to understand this
equivalence in a more precise way.
There is a natural functor $\mathsf{Top}_{BO} \to \mathsf{StVectBun}$,
defined by considering the vector bundles classified by the pullbacks
of a map $B \to BO$
along the inclusions $BO(n) \to BO$.
One can also go from stable bundles to spaces over $BO$
by taking classifying maps, though this requires making choices,
so it doesn't seem to really define a functor.
The category $\mathsf{Top}_{BO}$ has a model structure induced
by the usual Quillen model structure on $\mathsf{Top}$.
Presumably, there is a "natural" model structure
on $\mathsf{StVectBun}$ that makes these two categories Quillen equivalent, which
motivates the above question.
